# Hilbert series of polynomial ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $k$ be a field and $S=k[x]$ a polynomial ring with $\deg x = 1$. Then we know that $H_S(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}.$ Let $S'=k[y]$ with $\deg y = -1$ or $y=x^{-1}.$ Then I think that $H_{S'}(t)= \frac{-t}{1-t}.$

1) If $S$ and $S'$ are isomorphic shouldn't they have the same Hilbert series?
2) What is the Hilbert series for $k[x,y]$ and the Hilbert series for $k[x,x^{-1}]?$

Comment: 1) Isomorphic doesn't mean *graded* isomorphic. 2) You should know the Hilbert series of $k[x,y]$. Recall that $k[x,x^{-1}]_n=kx^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. Then the Hilbert function is constant $1$ and the Hilbert series is...

Comment: Oh yes, they aren't graded isomorphic. As for the Hilbert series for $K[x,y]$ as I defined them should be the same as the Hilbert series for $K[x,x^{-1}]$ and is equal with 0?

Comment: Well, I understand now that you want to find out the Hilbert series of $k[x,y]$ when $\deg x=1$ and $\deg y=-1$. But how one defines the Hilbert series in this case, since the graded components are infinitely dimensional?

Comment: Then I guess you can,t. Thanks a lot for the help.